# Is it possible to have an array of instances which take a generic parameter without knowing (or caring) what the parameter is?

Tags: swift, generics

Consider the following test case, which contains a 'factory' class which is able to call a closure it contains, providing a new instance of some 'defaultable' type:

```
protocol Defaultable {
    init()
}

extension Int:    Defaultable { }
extension Double: Defaultable { }
extension String: Defaultable { }

class Factory<T : Defaultable> {
    let resultHandler: (T) -> ()

    init(resultHandler: (T) -> ()) {
        self.resultHandler = resultHandler
    }

    func callResultHandler() {
        resultHandler(T.init())
    }
}
```

Now, this works well when I use it on its own, where I can keep track of the generic type:

```
// Create Int factory variant...
let integerFactory = Factory(resultHandler: { (i: Int) in print("The default integer is \(i)") })

// Call factory variant...
integerFactory.callResultHandler()
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work so well if I want to use factories in a way where I can't keep track of the generic type:

```
// Create a queue of factories of some unknown generic type...
var factoryQueue = [Factory]()

// Add factories to the queue...
factoryQueue.append(integerFactory)
factoryQueue.append(doubleFactory)
factoryQueue.append(stringFactory)

// Call the handler for each factory...
for factory in factoryQueue {
    factory.callResultHandler()
}
```

I understand the error I get (*Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred*), but I don't understand why I can't do this, because when I interact with the array, I don't need to know what the generic parameter is (I don't interact with any of the generic things in the `Factory` instance). Is there any way I can achieve the above?

Note that the above is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do; in actuality I'm designing a download manager where it can infer what type of file I want (JSON, image, etc.) using generics; the protocol actually contains an `init(data:) throws` initialiser instead. I want to be able to add the download objects to a queue, but I can't think of any way of adding them to a queue because of the generic nature of the download objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently came back to needing a better answer for this question—as I was performing some refactoring—and thought that it would be really useful to have generic properties of the class, which of course would mean that the class itself would have to be generic as well.

I'm not sure why it didn't occur to me before, but I can simply create a protocol which mirrors the non-generic methods of the class. Using the example I originally had in my question, I could create a `FactoryProtocol` like so:

```
protocol FactoryProtocol {
    func callResultHandler()
}
```

Make the class conform to it:

```
class Factory<T : Defaultable>: FactoryProtocol
```

And then use the protocol rather than the class when I define my array:

```
var factoryQueue = [FactoryProtocol]()
```

This allows me to add any type of specialised `Factory` to the array and interact with the non-generic methods as I please.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Swift's strict type safety means you cannot mix two instances of the same class with different generic parameters. They are effectively seen as completely different types.

However in your case, all you're doing is passing a closure to a `Factory` instance that takes a `T` input, and then invoking it at any given time with `T.init()`. Therefore, you can create a closed system in order to contain the type of `T`, meaning that you don't actually need your generic parameter to be at the scope of your class. You can instead restrict it to just the scope of the initialiser.

You can do this by defining your `resultHandler` as a `Void->Void` closure, and create it by wrapping the passed closure in the initialiser with another closure – and then passing in `T.init()` into the closure provided (ensuring a new instance is created on each invocation).

Now whenever you call your `resultHandler`, it will create a new instance of the type you define in the closure that you pass in – and pass that instance to the closure.

This doesn't break Swift's type safety rules, as the result of `T.init()` is still known due to the explicit typing in the closure you pass. This new instance is then being passed into your closure that has a matching input type. Also, because you never pass the result of `T.init()` to the outside world, you never have to expose the type in your `Factory` class definition.

As your `Factory` class *itself* no longer has a generic parameter, you can mix different instances of it together freely.

For example:

```
class Factory {
    let resultHandler: () -> ()

    init<T:Defaultable>(resultHandler: (T) -> ()) {
        self.resultHandler = {
            resultHandler(T.init())
        }
    }

    func callResultHandler() {
        resultHandler()
    }
}

// Create Int factory variant...
let integerFactory = Factory(resultHandler: { (i: Int) in debugPrint(i) })

// Create String factory variant...
let stringFactory = Factory(resultHandler: { (i: String) in debugPrint(i) })

// Create a queue of factories of some unknown generic type...
var factoryQueue = [Factory]()

// Add factories to the queue...
factoryQueue.append(integerFactory)
factoryQueue.append(stringFactory)

// Call the handler for each factory...
for factory in factoryQueue {
    factory.callResultHandler()
}

// prints:
// 0
// ""
```

In order to adapt this to take an `NSData` input, you can simply modify the `resultHandler` closure & `callResultHandler()` function to take an `NSData` input. You then just have to modify the wrapped closure in your initialiser to use your `init(data:) throws` initialiser, and convert the result to an optional or do your own error handling to deal with the fact that it can throw.

For example:

```
class Factory {
    let resultHandler: (NSData) -> ()

    init<T:Defaultable>(resultHandler: (T?) -> ()) {
        self.resultHandler = {data in
            resultHandler(try? T.init(data:data)) // do custom error handling here if you wish
        }
    }

    func callResultHandler(data:NSData) {
        resultHandler(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is clever, I'm not 100% sure it can be applied to my particular case (download manager as described in last paragraph), but I think it might be able to, I'll give it a go...

Comment: @Robert Pretty sure you could get it to work, you should just have to modify the `resultHandler` to be an `(NSData)->()`, and then change your `callResultHandler()` function to take an `NSData` input. I'll edit my answer to give an example of this.

Comment: @Robert Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this is not possible. The reason for this is that Swift doesn't have first class metatypes. I can imagine all sorts of Monads and Functors being built if this was possible. Unfortunately, this is a limitation. Welcome to Swift.

The golden rule is that in Swift, you cannot nail a type down to a protocol. Swift *needs* a concrete type.

Check [this](http://robnapier.net/erasure) article out for more details around the subject.

Comment: I realise that, however I really need the queue to accept multiple types.